# Why did the Chitauri need Loki at all?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

If the Chitauri scepter has an Infinity Stone within it, and it can be used to "activate" the Tesseract so that a person (or people) can travel from one galaxy to the next... why do the Chitauri need Loki at all in *The Avengers*?

Why not just use the scepter, start their own war on earth and get the Tesseract themselves?

Comment: It's worth noting that the Chitauri sceptre mention most likely actually belongs to Thanos - "He who put the sceptre in your hands" - and we do not currently know if it contains an Infinity Stone or not. This will most likely be answered in Avengers: Age of Ultron or beyond.

Comment: @DrRDizzle It has been answered in AoU. It Did have an Infinity Stone, the Mind Gem.

Comment: As for `it can be used to "activate" the Tesseract `, the Scepter played no part in activating the Tesseract. It was used to pierce the shield protecting it though.

Comment: @cde not from every question, but only those which don't need. This tag has approx 60 question , out of which some uses asks question specific to MCU ,some asks question covering multiple movie from MCU that is also fine.BUt some questions are very specific to single movie , those i will remove whenver i find having this tag.

Comment: Ok sure sorry my mistake , I didn't check meta. However its description seems to reflect something else

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They didn't need Loki, they needed [Dr Erik Selvig](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Erik_Selvig): or to be totally accurate, they needed someone to open the gate for them (or in the case of the Avengers, an orchestrated attempt *to use the power of* the Scepter to create the second half of a 'bridge' for the dimensional vortex to work)

Loki was their agent, and he used his cunning and craft to manipulate the relevant factors, and find elements that could integrate the power of the *Tesseract* with the *Mind Stone* within Loki's staff to achieve just such an event.

They didn't need Loki, they needed a way onto earth. Loki promised to provide it to them, should they grant him possession of the Scepter.

Comment: Same comment I added to the main question - 




The Chitauri sceptre mentioned most likely actually belongs to Thanos - "He who put the sceptre in your hands" - and we do not currently know if it contains an Infinity Stone or not. This will most likely be answered in Avengers: Age of Ultron or beyond.

Comment: @DrRDizzle, it's [been confirmed a few times](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity_Stones) now that the sceptre contains the Mind Stone... they're just unsure of its actual appearance/colour, as there is already a blue infinity stone.. silver? grey?

Comment: Actually, that's just a Wiki page - it's fairly obvious that Loki's Sceptre COULD be an Infinity Stone if the writers want it too, but it hasn't actually been confirmed yet.

Comment: Also, the 'sources' in that Wiki page lead to unsubstantiated rumuours, one of the articles specifically claiming that Marvel have stated that Loki's Sceptre DOES contain an Infinity Stone, but that it isn't the Mind Stone. Either way, it's too soon to claim that it's the Mind Stone and will be until something more solid comes up - like atually seeing Avengers: Age of Ulton.